# I have a custom exception I want to throw in one function and catch in another, it isn't working

Tags: c++, exception

So I have a custom exception class "ExceptionLinkedAccess".

I have a function "find" in another class that will throw this exception. I have another function in the same class as "find" called "insert", and this function will call "find".

I need to catch the exception thrown by find. So, I use a try/catch block but it doesn't work because the program just ends when the exception is thrown.

Unfortunately I am unable to change any of the function signatures or declarations.

```
template <typename T>
class OULinkedList {
    template <typename F>
    friend class OULinkedListEnumerator;
private:
    Comparator<T>* comparator = NULL;               // used to determine list order and item equality
    unsigned long size = 0;                         // actual number of items currently in list
    OULink<T>* first = NULL;                        // pointer to first link in list
    OULink<T>* last = NULL;                         // pointer to last link in list
public:
    OULinkedList(Comparator<T>* comparator);        // creates empty linked list with comparator
    virtual ~OULinkedList();                        // deletes all links and their data items
    void DisplayList();                     

    // if an equivalent item is not already present, insert item in order and return true
    // if an equivalent item is already present, leave list unchanged and return false
    bool insert(const T* item);

    // if item is greater than item at last, append item at end and return true
    // if item is less than or equal to item at last, leave list unchanged and return false
    bool append(const T* item);

    // if an equivalent item is already present, replace item and return true
    // if an equivalent item is not already present, leave list unchanged and return false
    bool replace(T* item);

    // if an equivalent item is already present, remove item and return true
    // if an equivalent item is not already present, leave list unchanged and return false
    bool remove(T* item);

    // if any items are present, return a copy of the first item
    // if no items are present, throw new ExceptionLinkedListAccess
    T get() const;

    // if an equivalent item is present, return a copy of the first such item
    // if an equivalent item is not present, throw a new ExceptionLinkedListAccess
    T find(const T* item) const;

    unsigned long getSize() const;                  // returns the current number of items in the list

    OULinkedListEnumerator<T> enumerator() const;   // create an enumerator for this linked list
};

// Implementation goes here
template<typename T>
 OULinkedList<T>::~OULinkedList(){
    delete comparator;
    delete first;
    delete last;

    if(comparator != NULL){
        comparator = NULL;
    }
    if(first != NULL){
        first = NULL;
    }
    if(last != NULL){
        last = NULL;
    }

 }


template<typename T>
OULinkedList<T>::OULinkedList(Comparator<T>* comparator){
    this->comparator = comparator;
}

// if an equivalent item is not already present, insert item in order and return true
// if an equivalent item is already present, leave list unchanged and return false
template <typename T>
bool OULinkedList<T>::insert(const T* item){
    //check if exist

    try{

        find(item);

    }catch(ExceptionLinkedListAccess ex){

        if(!append(item)){

        std::cout << "INSERTING" << std::endl;
        }
    }

}


// if item is greater than item at last, append item at end and return true
// if item is less than or equal to item at last, leave list unchanged and return false
template <typename T>
bool OULinkedList<T>::append(const T* item) {



    if(this->first == NULL){

        this->first = new OULink<T>(item);

        this->last = first;
        size++;

        return true;

    }else if(comparator->compare(*item, *this->last->data) > 0){ 

        this->last->next = new OULink<T>(item);
        this->last = this->last->next;
        // delete if not working
        this->last->next = NULL;

        size++;
        return true;

    }else{

        return false;

    }

}


template <typename T>
bool OULinkedList<T>::replace(T* item){
    return false;

}


// if an equivalent item is already present, remove item and return true
// if an equivalent item is not already present, leave list unchanged and return false
template <typename T>
bool OULinkedList<T>::remove(T* item){
    OULinkedListEnumerator<T> listEnum(this->first);
    // Special case, remove head
    if(listEnum->current == NULL && this->first){
        OULink<T>* successorNode = this->first->next;
        if(successorNode == NULL){
            this->last = NULL;
        }
}

    return true;
}


// if any items are present, return a copy of the first item
// if no items are present, throw new ExceptionLinkedListAccess
template <typename T>
T OULinkedList<T>::get() const{
    OULinkedListEnumerator<T> linkE(this->first);
    return linkE.peek();

}


// if an equivalent item is present, return a copy of the first such item
// if an equivalent item is not present, throw a new ExceptionLinkedListAccess
template <typename T>
T OULinkedList<T>::find(const T* item) const {
    OULink<T>* currentNode = this->first;

    while(currentNode != NULL){
        if(comparator->compare(*currentNode->data,*item) == 0){
            return *currentNode->data;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    throw  new ExceptionLinkedListAccess;
}
```

And here is my Exception.h:

```
class Exception {};
class ExceptionIndexOutOfRange : Exception {};
class ExceptionMemoryNotAvailable : Exception {};
class ExceptionLinkedListAccess : Exception {};
class ExceptionEnumerationBeyondEnd : Exception {};
```

Comment: Did you mean to have `new` in `throw  new ExceptionLinkedListAccess;`

Comment: C++ is not Java and `new` has a different meaning in both languages. `new` in C++ returns a **pointer** to a class. Don't use `new` and it should be fine.

Comment: Note: in *general* you want to catch exceptions by const reference (`const &`), *not* by value.

Comment: Btw; all that explicit `this` dereference (`this->`) you are doing is completely unnecessary and is, to many people, just noise.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen If you will answer, I can check you off (if you care). Thank you.

Comment: Throw a pointer, catch a  pointer.

Comment: You shouldn't use Java as a model when writing C++ code.  Things like this will keep tripping you up if you assume that similar syntax means both languages do the same thing.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Please write your answer _in the answer section_!!!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As pointed out by Yksisarvinen, the new keyword works differently in java and c++.

I removed the new and I am now able to catch the exception.